# Pipeline job fails after tests complete

Tags: python, gitlab-pipelines

There is job script:

```
image: python:3.7.9

stages:
    - test

run_ui_tests:
    tags:
        - est
    stage: test
    before_script:
        - echo "Prepairing enviroment..."
        - python --version
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
    script:
        - echo "Executing ui tests with Pytest..."
        - cd cio_tests
        - pytest -v authorize_test.py
    after_script:
        - echo "Cleaning test catalogue..."
```

job fails after all tests are completed:
[image]

What is the reason for this behaviour? After all, the tests are completed and one of the tests found a bug

Comment: `What is the reason for this behaviour?` What _exactly_ do you have in mind? What exactly is _this_ behavior? `After all, the tests are completed and one of the tests found a bug` ? Becaues one test failed.

Comment: the `logs` are showing you everything, the job has failed since he couldn't pass the last test `FAILED authorize_test.py ...`

Comment: That sounds like the expected behavior. The job should fail because one or more of your tests failed.

Comment: Just because the tests completed, does not mean the job should succeed. A test fails, your application exits with exit code 1, and the job fails. This is the exact expected behavior of a CI job. If tests fail, you want the CI to fail to be able to detect changes that introduced bugs.

Comment: Okay, but how to make the job  succesfully ends?